# NameError: name 'mergelist' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

**NameError: name 'mergelist' is not defined**
**Here i have mentioned mergelist properly and have passed the same arguments but still it's showing NameError, I'am not able to understand where I'am wrong **

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data=data
        self.head=None
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def push(self, newdata):   
        newnode=node(newdata)
        newnode.next=self.head
        self.head=newnode
    def mergelist(self, l1, l2):
        dummy=listnode(0)
        pointer=dummy
        while(l1 and l2):
            if l1.data<=l2.data:
                pointer.next=l1
                l1=l1.next
            else:
                pointer.next=l2
                l2=l2.next
            pointer=pointer.next
        if l1 == None:
            pointer.next = l2
        else:
            pointer.next = l1
        return dummy.next   
    def printlist(self):
        temp=self.head
        while(temp):    

            print(temp.data)
            temp=temp.next            
llist1=linkedlist()
llist1.push(4)  
llist1.push(9)    
llist1.push(7)    
llist1.push(5)    
llist1.push(4)   

llist2=linkedlist() 
llist2.push(32)  
llist2.push(12)
llist2.push(1)
llist2.push(2)
llist2.push(8)
llist1.printlist()
llist2.printlist() 

llist3=linkedlist()
llist3.head=mergelist(llist1.head, llist2.head)

llist3.printlist()
```

*This is the error i'm getting*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `mergelist` as a global func like this `llist3.head=mergelist(llist1.head, llist2.head)` when it is in fact defined inside a class, more specifically the `linkedlist` class. One option you have is to move `mergelist` outside like so

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data=data
        self.head=None
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def push(self, newdata):
        newnode=node(newdata)
        newnode.next=self.head
        self.head=newnode

    def printlist(self):
        temp=self.head
        while(temp):

            print(temp.data)
            temp=temp.next


def mergelist(l1, l2):
    dummy=listnode(0)
    pointer=dummy
    while(l1 and l2):
        if l1.data<=l2.data:
            pointer.next=l1
            l1=l1.next
        else:
            pointer.next=l2
            l2=l2.next
        pointer=pointer.next
    if l1 == None:
        pointer.next = l2
    else:
            pointer.next = l1


llist1=linkedlist()
llist1.push(4)
llist1.push(9)
llist1.push(7)
llist1.push(5)
llist1.push(4)

llist2=linkedlist()
llist2.push(32)
llist2.push(12)
llist2.push(1)
llist2.push(2)
llist2.push(8)
llist1.printlist()
llist2.printlist()

llist3=linkedlist()
llist3.head=mergelist(llist1.head, llist2.head)

llist3.printlist()
```

Of course you now have new errors like `listnode` not being defined. But I presume you know how to define those.

An other option you have is to invoke `mergelist` by prefixing it with the `linkedlist` object and the `.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

`mergelist` is within the `linkedlist` class, so you'd have to call it like this:

```
llist3.head = linkedlist.mergelist(llist1.head, llist2.head)
```

Also, since `mergelist` doesn't actually use `self`, you could decorate it as a `@staticmethod` and not have it accept `self` as the first argument, or you could just take it out of the `linkedlist` class as in Srini's answer